# Cant change sound configuration from 2 to 5.1

Tags: 16.04, sound

Im using the sound app that comes preloaded on ubuntu 16.04LTS, and came across the configuration late night while inebriated. Realized this was the source as to why my subwoofer wasnt working properly. Currently, I believe that its set to the 2 configuration and need to change it to 5.1. If I remember correctly, it was a dropbox within the app that I havent been able to find sober. If anyone can help, please do.

Comment: What is your computer make and model? Is it a laptop with internal sub-woofer like mine, or external sub-woofer? If external how is it connected and what brand is it? Plus any other details you think relevant... excluding favorite beverages.

Comment: its an external subwoofer connected through the aux. the brand is "creative". Under the sound tab, it says im playing osund through my graphics card. Its an HDMI Radeon R7 360/R9 360 OEM